# Draper Gem resulting in Undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, draper

I have used draper with some success. But currently I'm stuck.

I have two models:

```
# Foo.rb
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :bars


# Bar.rb
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :foo

    def self.number_banned
      where(:status => "banned").count
    end
```

If the class is loaded normally, it works as expected:

```
f = Foo.find(1)
f.bars.number_banned  # ex. 3
```

If I use Draper to decorate the objects, it returns an undefined "number_banned" method:

```
f = Foo.find(1).decorate
f.bars.number_banned  # Undefined method 'number_banned'
```

To note:

- Both Decorators include the delegate_all option
- FooDecorator decorates_association :bars

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the decorators code and the full error stack, please?

Comment: Shouldn't your second model be `class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: @pdoherty926 . You are correct. I have updated above

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the comments. I seem to have found a solution.

The FooDecorates method should point to a singular instance of Bar:

```
 decorates_association :bar
```

And not:

```
decorates_association :bars
```